# Sending Signals in C and two Integers

Tags: c, signals

Can you help me with the following task:

Write a C program that interprets command line parameters 1 and 2 as pid and signal number and sends the corresponding signal number to the process pid. To interpret command line parameters as integers, you can use the C function atoi. The user is to be informed via standard output how successful the process was. In addition, suitable exit codes are to be used.

Here my code:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<wait.h>
#include<signal.h>

// Taking argument as command line
void signal_handler(int sig)
{
    printf("a = %d, b = %d \n",a,b),
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a, b;
  
    // Checking if number of argument is
    // equal to 2 or not.
    if (argc < 2 || argc > 3) 
    {
        printf("enter 2 arguments only eg.\"filename arg1 arg2 !!\"");
        return 0;
    }
    
    // Converting string type to integer type
    // using function "atoi( argument)"
    a = atoi(argv[1]); 
    b = atoi(argv[2]);
    
    // Checking if all the numbers are positive of not
    if (a < 0 || b < 0) 
    {
        printf("enter only positive values in arguments !!");
        return 1;
    }
    
    pid_t pid;
    signal(SIGUSR1,sig_handler);
    pid=getpid();     
    kill(pid,SIGUSR1);
    return 0;
    
}
```

Is that right? Or what can be improved and simplified?

Comment: You have gone to all this trouble to parse and verify the command line arguments, but then when you actually call `kill`, the pid is always the current process and the signal is always SIGUSR1.  I think you just want something like `kill(a,b)`.  I also am not sure why you are installing a signal handler; that doesn't seem to have anything to do with the assigned task.

Comment: And you should check whether the `kill` system call succeeded, and report to the user if it failed.

Answer (score 0):

At the end you are killing your own program, not the program that was given to you (`getpid()` returns the PID to your own program). All you have to do is this:

```
if (kill(a, b) < 0) {
    // error...
}
```

Just make sure that `a` is the PID and `b` is the signal number. You may want to rename those variables.